# Unexpected evaluation of "optional" variables in karate schema validation

Tags: karate

I am attempting to validate a payload against a complex schema using karate. The complexity, among other properties, is caused by optional nested objects (with, again, optional properties).

However, when *first* defining the inner (nested) schema, and referencing that schema in the "outer" schema, the variable for the inner schema is resolved immediately, even if it is marked as optional (using the "##(nestedSchema)" syntax). Reversing both declarations results in the expected behavior.

The following feature demonstrates the issue: The first scenario is successful, the second is not. Also, the second log statement shows that the variable is instantly resolved.

I was not expecting this behavior. Should I file a bug?

However, I understand that the "optional variable" is instantly evaluated, as it is present at the time of evaluation. Is there any other way to define my optional schema attributes? In my real-world feature file, I am read()ing the schema definitions rather than defining them in-place.

```
Feature: Nested optional schema

  Background:

    * def sut = { "id": "123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000" }

  Scenario: Optional nested schema is optional

    * def outerSchema = { "id": "#uuid", "nested": "##(nestedSchema)" }
    * def nestedSchema = { "attribute": "#string" }

    * karate.log(outerSchema)

    Then match sut contains outerSchema

  Scenario: Optional nested schema is optional (reversed order -- fails)

    * def nestedSchema = { "attribute": "#string" }
    * def outerSchema = { "id": "#uuid", "nested": "##(nestedSchema)" }

    * karate.log(outerSchema)

    Then match sut contains outerSchema
```

Comment: I think you ran in to the exact problem, so I marked this as duplicate. let me know if not the case

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks so much for your response.
Yes, this *is* the same issue, and using the "json foo = karate.readAsString" (or the round brackets, fwiw) solve my issue.

Sorry for creating a duplicate. The connection between these issues was not obvious for me.

Comment: no worries, was checking because some times it turns out to not be a duplicate. glad it works for you now